# React Components: How To Structure React Live Search Form With Infinite Scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, structure, composition

I'm creating a React Movie app which enables user to search for movies and add to his favorite list. This app is going to have a live search functionality with infinite loading feature so when user enters a title name a Modal will display results and user can select titles to be added to his list.

I'm so confused about managing live search and infinite loading state and their dependency. So is this approach correct or search results should be part of live search component?

```
const App = () => {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [reqQuery, setReqQuery] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Request from API and store in the searchResults
  }, [reqQuery]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Render Results
  }, [searchResults]);

  return (
    <>
      <SearchForm onConfirmedInput={(query) => setReqQuery(query)} />
      {searchResults && <Results data={searchResults} />}
    </>
  );
};

const SearchForm = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    setValue(val);
    // If value is valid then lift-up
    props.onConfirmedInput(value);
  };

  return <input value={value} onChange={handleChange}></input>;
};
```

P.S: Mentioned code is just to elaborate the issue and is not part actual app code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is sound - storing state at a higher level and having `SearchForm` be a component that just uses its passed in `props`. A few pointers

- Create a container component for the "page" i.e. `<Movies>`. Your `<App>` should be kept for things like routing and not be concerned with implementation details of specific parts of functionality. I realise you may have been trying to keep things simple and your example uncluttered, I mentioned just in case.
- the way you are using `useEffect` will work, however it isn't best practice. You should declare functions (e.g. `getSearchResults`) for API calls (and more ideally, declare them in a separate service, rather than having `fetch` in the component code)  and pass these into your `SearchForm` rather than relying on `useEffect`. When the state changes (e.g. after the API is called and results returned) the component will be re-rendered after you `setSearchResults(results)` and pass them down to the `<SearchForm>`

For infinite scroll with lazy loading I'd highly recommend the excellent [`react-window` library](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) and associated components for lzay loading and auto-resize.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.  Yes I'm going to use helper functions to fetch data and passing them down to the `SearchForm` is great idea too, this way I can prevent unnecessary re-renders. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! The lazy loading / infinite scrolling can be tricky so do things like the autosizing last, just get it working and worry about looks later. I learned this from experience :) let me know if you are having issues and I can share my implementation